# Generate a unique local storage key per web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage

I'm making a NPM package that needs to save information in the browser local storage to be used by web frameworks like Angular, React and Vue. The problem is that i don't know how to properly generate a key. I was thinking about generating a UUID to be saved as a local storage key but if the user opens two windows with the same web app, then they will generate two different UUID's, so they will have different storages. I also thought about just using a harcoded name, because localstorage is not shared between domains, but if the user is testing his application in localhost, then the storage can be mixed with other app he has also tested in localhost. Is it possible to know the package name of who's calling my package so i can generate a local storage key with that? I don't want to ask the developer for a unique local storage key when he uses my package!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your full use case, it's hard to say, but if I understand correctly, you want to create a package, I'll call it `fooLib`, and your concern is if that project is used in `projA` and `projB`:

If you use a static key, like `fooLibKey`:

- `projA` and `projB` will both be using the same storage

If you use a dynamically-generated key, such as a UUID:

- Every time you reload the page, you'll lose your store.

I suspect what you should do is allow the dependent projects (`projA`, `projB`, etc.) configure the key:

```
// in projA
import fooLib from 'foo-lib'

fooLib.init({
  keyName: 'projAFooLib',
})
```

There's no reliable way to get the name of the client package.  In a Node project, you could walk your way up until you find a `package.json` file and try to infer it from that, but that's pretty risky, and there's no real way to do that in a browser-based project.

Comment: Exactly. But i want to avoid asking the developer for the key. I want the library to be as simple as it can be. I don't think i have another possible option, tho. But i asked to see if some StackOverFlow genius has an idea

Comment: Nope, I think you're stuck on this one...I just updated my answer.  There's no real, reliable way to correctly infer the key.  I don't think this is a particularly onerous configuration step -- sometimes simple is "as simple as possible."  I think good documentation will trump simplicity of use any day.